# Issue with Pagintation

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, instagram

I am trying to use the Instagram API for Pagination in my iOS App. However whenever I add my new pictures to my existing array I get this Error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

Here is my code on how to get the initial set of Instagram Images:

```
- (void)fetchInstagramPics {
    NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL *status = [user boolForKey:@"isInstagramLoggedIn"];
    if (status) {
        [[InstagramClient sharedClient] getPath:@"users/self/feed"
                                     parameters:nil
                                        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                            // NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
                                            self.timelineResponse = [responseObject mutableCopy];
                                            [instaPics addObjectsFromArray:responseObject[@"data"]];
                                            [self updateArrays];
                                            [self.tableView reloadData];
                                        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                            NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
                                        }];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData]; });
}
```

Here is how I am attempting to add more pictures into the `instaPics` Array:

```
- (void)nextInstagramPage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *page = self.timelineResponse[@"pagination"];
    NSString *nextPage = page[@"next_url"];

    [[InstagramClient sharedClient] getPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nextPage] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        self.timelineResponse = [responseObject mutableCopy];
        [self.timelineResponse addEntriesFromDictionary:responseObject];
        [instaPics addObjectsFromArray:responseObject[@"data"]];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
    }];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == roundf(scrollView.contentSize.height-scrollView.frame.size.height)) {
        NSLog(@"we are at the endddd");
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self nextInstagramPage:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Here are all the properties defined in the Header file of this class:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *instaPics;
@property (strong, nonatomic) AFOAuth1Client *twitterClient;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *tweets;
```

//Edit: Now have the construction of the Cells:

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0)  {
            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TweetCell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

            NSDictionary *tweet = tweets[indexPath.row];

            return cell;

        }else {

            static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"InstagramCell";
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]];

            NSDictionary *entry = instaPics[indexPath.row];

            return cell;
        }

}
```

Comment: how do you init your instaPics ?

Comment: `@synthesize instaPics;`

Comment: i means i don't find the init method such as self.instaPics = [NSMutableArray array]; in your paste code

Comment: What do you mean all I have done Is shown in the code above

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the NSMutableArray, add `instaPics = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` in `fetchInstagramPics`

Comment: Now the issue changes because I have made it so that the instagram cell is every other row in the `indexPath` therefore I now get an error here where I construct the interface of each cell: `    NSDictionary *entry = instaPics[indexPath.row / 2];`

Comment: I have now added how I construct the cells into the original question

Comment: @prnk28 is instaPics[indexPath.row / 2] not working? what error are you seeing? (you should give credit for first issue and open new issue :) )